# How to add a table header to this div-table within a script?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, html-table

I got this `div-table` populated dynamically, but I can't find a way to add a header to it, given the way this is being built.

`HTML` piece:

```
<div class="block div-table" id="sidebar-record-block"></div>
```

This is the script populating the table dynamically:

```
function showRecord(record) {
    if (record.length) {
      for (var i = 0; i < record.length; i++) {
        // build field name on the fly, formatted field-1234
        var str = '' + i;
        var fieldId = 'field-' + ('0000' + str).substring(str.length)

        // If this field # doesn't already exist on the page, create it
        if (!$('#'+fieldId).length) {
          var newField = $($.parseHTML('<div id="'+fieldId+'"></div>'));
          $('#sidebar-record-block').append(newField);
        }

        // Replace content of the field div with new record
        $('#'+fieldId).replaceWith('<div id="'+fieldId+'" class="div-table-row"></div>');
        $('#'+fieldId).append('<input id=checkBox type="checkbox"</input>')
                      .append($('<div class="div-table-th">' + record[i].heading + '</div>'))
                      .append('<div class="div-table-td">' + record[i].cellval + '</div>')             
      }  
    }
```

Here's how css is:

```
.div-table {
    display: table;
    width: auto;
    border-spacing: 3px;
  }

  .div-table-row {
    display: table-row;
    width: auto;
    clear: both; 
 }

  .div-table-td,
  .div-table-th {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 190px;
    background-color: rgb(245, 241, 239);
  }
```

Here's the expected result:
[image]
Appreciate your help!

Comment: You're talking about adding a `<th>` element to a `<div>`?

Comment: Hi, @obscure! The div-table class is used to make a group of divs behave like a table. Therefore, I'm not sure how to add that in that case. I've tried w3school's approach, but I didn't succeed.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't simply add an `<th>` element to a `<div>` as the `<th>` needs to be a children of a `<table>` element. Or is the CSS class `div-table-th` your self-made `<th>` equivalent Antonio?

Comment: Just added a bit of it above, @obscure. Sorry I'm still quite unfamiliar with all this, but jumping into it lately. Thanks for checking!

Comment: Could you also provide some sample data (the `record` object) and maybe even an image of how the final result should look like?

Comment: Just did it, @obscure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you have almost anything you need yet. The trick is just adding the headings for your rows as a different styled row element to your custom table.

For example:

```css
.div-table {
    display: table;
    width: auto;
    border-spacing: 3px;
  }

  .div-table-row {
    display: table-row;
    width: auto;
    clear: both; 
 }

  .div-table-td,
  .div-table-th {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 190px;
    background-color: rgb(245, 241, 239);
  }
  
  .div-table-header {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 190px;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<div class="block div-table" id="sidebar-record-block">
  <div class="div-table-row">
    <div>Sel</div>
    <div class="div-table-header">Color</div>
    <div class="div-table-header">Hex</div>
  </div>
  <div class="div-table-row">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <div class="div-table-th">amarelo suave</div>
    <div class="div-table-td">EEEA97</div>
  </div>
  <div class="div-table-row">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <div class="div-table-th">verde</div>
    <div class="div-table-td">00FF00</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Creating this dynamically at runtime isn't much different from the code you already have.

Just add the following at the beginning of your for-loop:

```
if(i==0) {
   $('#sidebar-record-block').append($($.parseHTML('<div class="div-table-row"><div>Sel</div><div class="div-table-header">Color</div><div class="div-table-header">Hex</div></div>')));
      }
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you!